# Draw multiple Google charts in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to draw multiple Google charts in a for loop, but can't seem to make it work. I have seen some similar questions being asked, but only with PHP. Anyone who can help? This is what I have tried so far https://jsfiddle.net/8nfbz1v1/

```
        <ul id="draw-charts"></ul>
```

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

for(var i = 0; i>6; i+){
var charts = "";
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawCharts() {

  charts += '<td><div id="chart_div' + i +'" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>';
  $("#draw-charts").html(charts);

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 1],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 2],
      ['Zucchini', 2],
      ['Pepperoni', 1]
    ]);

    var options = {title:'How Much Pizza Sarah Ate Last Night',
                   width:400,
                   height:300};

    // Instantiate and draw the chart for Sarah's pizza.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div' + i));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setOnLoadCallback` should only be called once per page load

once it fires, you can draw as many charts as needed

you can also include the `callback` in the `load` statement

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 1],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 2],
      ['Zucchini', 2],
      ['Pepperoni', 1]
    ]);
    var options = {
      title:'How Much Pizza Sarah Ate Last Night',
      width:400,
      height:300
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      var container = document.getElementById('draw-charts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<ul id="draw-charts"></ul>
```