# Multiple onload callbacks required to draw multiple Google pie charts?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am trying to get multiple pie charts to display on a page. I am looking at this article:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts

The **problem** with my code is only one chart is displayed. My code should display at least 8 or 9 charts, instead of just one.

My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    const results = JSON.parse('{{{input}}}');

    results.forEach(function (r, i) {

      let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Answered', 'Count'],
        ['Answered', r.answeredCount],
        ['Unanswered', r.unansweredCount]
      ]);

      let options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities'
      };

      let el = document.createElement('div');

      let chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(el);
      chart.draw(data, options);
      document.body.appendChild(el);

    });

  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

like the article says, do I really need to use multiple calls to `setOnLoadCallback()`? It doesn't really make much sense...anyone know what could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the chart that's being drawn the last one in your dataset? You do need multiple 'google.charts.setOnLoadCallback', but you can wrap them together in a function and call that.

Comment: your issue may be with `results`. What is the value of `results`?

Comment: only one callback is needed per page load, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42725725/5090771) for a working example...

Comment: yeah @WhiteHat that makes sense, I just read the first half of the article, then later it says you don't need multiple callbacks, which makes a lot more sense..there should be no need for multiple callbacks!